# RPC vs restful endpoints

Tags: rest, rpc

I've spent more time than I'd like to admit trying to understand the differences between RPC and restful endpoints. In fact, after going down this rabbit hole, I'm not even sure I fully understand what RPC is anymore. And I'm not alone. I see countless messages repeatedly asking for clarification.

Here's my understanding so far:

RPC and restful endpoints are largely conceptual in nature only. There are no standards.

Both are ways of invoking a function on a remote server.

In the case of restful endpoints, we map HTTP methods to CRUD operations on a resource.

In the case of RPC, we're concerned w/actions on an object.

However, in both cases, we're addressing remote method invocation.

I've read some folks say restful shouldn't be stateful and if it is, it's not restful. But aren't most restful endpoints using state via sessions? I mean, I'm not going to let just anyone delete data w/o being logged in.

And I've also read that functions like domain(.)com/login isn't restful b/c it's an action. This seems to make sense, but since I'm not writing my functions any differently on my server than I would a simple restful function, does it really matter what we call them -- restful vs. RPC.

I truly just don't understand what I'm missing and no posts thus far on StackOverflow appear to address this confusion.

Hoping someone can provide some insight using the above as a guide for understanding. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an amazing question. There is a huge difference between REST and RPC approaches, I'll try to explain it.

RPC just lets you call some remote computer to make some job. It can be any job, and it can have any inputs and outputs. When you design API, you just define how to name this job operation and which inputs and outputs it will have.

### Step 1. Just RPC

For example, you could have operation `foo` with one input and two outputs like that (I will use [JSight API](https://jsight.io/docs/jsight-api-0-3-quick-tutorial/) notation because it supports both RPC and REST API types):

```
JSIGHT 0.3

URL /rpc-api
  Protocol json-rpc-2.0
  Method foo
    Params
      {
        "input-1": 123 // some integer
      }
    Result
      {
        "output-1": 123, // some other integer
        "output-2": "some string"
      }
```

When you design your RPC API you can use as many such operations as you want.

So, what's the problem with this? Why do we need REST, if we already have RPC?

The problems are the following:

1. When you look at the method `foo` definition you do not have the slightest idea, what it does.
2. When you design RPC APIs you have absolute freedom, but freedom often can be a bad thing. Because people think in different fashions. You could think, that your API is easy and elegant, but other people would not think so.

### Step 2. Standardized RPC

If you are an experienced API designer and you use the RPC style, you will try to follow some pattern to avoid the two faults mentioned above. For example, let's imagine, that your `foo` method returns a customer entity. Then you will never call it like `foo`, you will call it `getCustomer`, like this:

```
JSIGHT 0.3

URL /rpc-api
  Protocol json-rpc-2.0
  Method getCustomer
    Params
      {
        "input-1": 123 // some integer
      }
    Result
      {
        "output-1": 123, // some other integer
        "output-2": "some string"
      }
```

Ok! Now when you just look at this description, you can say, that this method returns a customer; that parameter `input-1` is some filter, most possibly, ID; and `output-1` and `output-2` are some customer properties.

Look, just using the *standard* way of naming the method, we made our API much more easy-to-understand.

Still, why do we need REST? What's the problem here?

The problem is, that when you have dozens of such RPC methods, your API looks messy. E. g.:

```
JSIGHT 0.3

URL /rpc-api
  Protocol json-rpc-2.0
  Method getCustomer
  Method updateCustomer
  Method getCustomerFriends
  Method getCustomerFather
  Method askCustomerConfirmation
  # etc...
```

Why it is not easy to understand this bunch of methods? Because it is not the way our brain works. Our brain always groups *actions* by *entity*. You naturally think about an *entity*, and then about *actions*, you can do with it. E. g. what you can do with a *cup*? *Take*, *hide*, *break*, *wash*, *turn over*. And brain rarely thinks firstly about actions and then about entities. What can I *take*? Cup, ball, ice cream, ticket, wife. Not very natural.

So, what is REST about?

### Step 3. REST

*REST is about grouping entities and defining the most standard actions with these entities.*

In IT we usually create, read, write, or delete entities. That's why we have `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` methods in HTTP, which is de facto the only implementation of the REST style.

When we group our methods by entities, our API becomes much clearer. Look:

```
JSIGHT 0.3

GET  /customer/{id}
PUT  /customer/{id}
GET  /customer/{id}/friends
GET  /customer/{id}/father
POST /customer/{id}/ask-confirmation
```

It is much easier to perceive now than in the RPC-style example above.

### Conclusion

There are a lot of other issues, concerning differences between RPC and REST. REST has its faults as well as RPC. But I wanted to explain to you the main idea:

*REST is a standard, that helps you to organize your API in a user-friendly fashion, that is comfortable for the human brain, so any developer can quickly capture your API structure.*

*RPC is just a way of calling remote operations.*

All the examples above are gathered here: https://editor.jsight.io/r/g6XJwjV/1

Answer (score 3):

> I truly just don't understand what I'm missing

Not your fault, the literature sucks.

---

I think you may find [Jim Webber's 2011 guidance](https://vimeo.com/41763224) enlightening.

> Embrace HTTP as an application protocol.  HTTP is not a transport protocol which happens to go conveniently through port 80.  HTTP is an application protocol whose application domain is the transfer of documents over a network.

HTTP, like remote procedure calls, is a request/response protocol.  The client sends a message to the server, the server sends a message back.  Big deal.

But in the REST architectural style, we're *also* following the [uniform interface constraint](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5).  That means (among other things) that everybody understands requests the same way, and everybody interprets responses the same way.

And that in turn means that general purpose components (browsers, web crawlers, proxies) can understand the request and response messages, *and react intelligently to those messages*, without needing to know anything at all about the specialization of a particular resource.

In the case of HTTP, we're passing messages about the domain of documents; if I want information from you, I ask for the latest copy of your document.  If I want to send information to you, I send you a proposed modification to your document.  Maybe you respond to my modification by creating a new document and you tell me to go look at that.  And so on.

Useful business activity, then, becomes a side effect of manipulating these documents.  Or, expressed another way, the document metaphor is the facade we present to the world.

---

> And I've also read that functions like domain(.)com/login isn't restful b/c it's an action.

See above: the literature sucks.

Consider this resource identifier: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/login

Does it work like every other resource identifier on the web?  Yes.  The browser knows how to make a request to `GET` this resource, and when Merriam-Webster answers that the browser should instead look at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/log%20on then the browser fetches that resource as well.

The fact that "login"/"log on" are intransitive English verbs *does not matter*; it's an identifier, and that's all the browser needs to know.

Alternatively, consider this: URL shorteners *work*.

Resource identifiers are a lot like variable names in a computer program; so long as the identifier satisfies the production rules of your language, you can use anything you want.  The machines don't care.

The key idea is that resources are not actions, they are "information that can be named".  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/log%20on is the name of the document that describes Merriam-Webster's definition of the verb "log on".

Since the machines don't care what names we use, we can use the extra freedom that offers us to choose names that make life easier for people we care about.

---

> I've read some folks say restful shouldn't be stateful and if it is, it's not restful. But aren't most restful endpoints using state via sessions?

[Stateless communication](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) is a REST architectural constraint.

> each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server.

Cookies are one of the corners where [HTTP failed to satisfy](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_4_2) the stateless communication constraint.

> I'm not going to let just anyone delete data w/o being logged in.

Not a problem: every HTTP request carries its own Authorization metadata; you aren't supposed to "remember" previous messages in the conversation.  Instead, you verify the provided credentials every time.